# Can I get help fixing json error on Stripe checkout code?

Tags: php, jquery, json, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the stripe checkout example working from this webpage
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

When I run checkout.html in my ampps and click the button I get

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I dont have any json in the file although there are json files in the installation which determine the dependencies and I dont know how to use them, they are below

I am also confused as to how to include stripe since there's a line already in checkout.html that includes stripe but I know there is more than one type of stripe so this may be the problem

**checkout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buy cool new product</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="product">
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
          alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
        />
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
          <h5>$20.00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
    </section>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx");
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");
console.log('here');
    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("/create-checkout-session.php", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

**create-checkout-session.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_<key>');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'unit_amount' => 2000,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);

echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
```

**composer.lock**

```
{
  "_readme": [
      "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
      "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies",
      "This file is @generated automatically"
  ],
  "content-hash": "ac527dca9621a9d645e6d48b43a0121d",
  "packages": [
      {
          "name": "stripe/stripe-php",
          "version": "v7.56.0",
          "source": {
              "type": "git",
              "url": "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php.git",
              "reference": "987596ad7ca747ce498e13bc1e3d1a57fbeb94cc"
          },
          "dist": {
              "type": "zip",
              "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stripe/stripe-php/zipball/987596ad7ca747ce498e13bc1e3d1a57fbeb94cc",
              "reference": "987596ad7ca747ce498e13bc1e3d1a57fbeb94cc",
              "shasum": ""
          },
          "require": {
              "ext-curl": "*",
              "ext-json": "*",
              "ext-mbstring": "*",
              "php": ">=5.6.0"
          },
          "require-dev": {
              "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "2.16.1",
              "php-coveralls/php-coveralls": "^2.1",
              "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
              "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.3",
              "symfony/process": "~3.4"
          },
          "type": "library",
          "extra": {
              "branch-alias": {
                  "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
              }
          },
          "autoload": {
              "psr-4": {
                "Stripe\\": "lib/"
              }
          },
          "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
          "license": [
              "MIT"
          ],
          "authors": [
              {
                  "name": "Stripe and contributors",
                  "homepage": "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/contributors"
              }
          ],
          "description": "Stripe PHP Library",
          "homepage": "https://stripe.com/",
          "keywords": [
              "api",
              "payment processing",
              "stripe"
          ],
          "time": "2020-09-25T18:15:04+00:00"
      }
  ],
  "packages-dev": [],
  "aliases": [],
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "stability-flags": [],
  "prefer-stable": false,
  "prefer-lowest": false,
  "platform": [],
  "platform-dev": [],
  "plugin-api-version": "1.1.0"
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
      "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.56.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: you should look at your dev tools as to why the response is coming back as html. meaning your code, not stripes.

Comment: Can you paste the output of the response? Should be able to see this in the network tab of your browser.

Comment: This usually means you have an error in your PHP code. As others have mentioned you should look at your PHP logs and/or Stripe dashboard logs to see why you're returning an error to the client instead of JSON. Also you included your secret test key in your question, I've edited it out but you should roll your key immediately at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys

Comment: thanks paul missed that

Comment: turned out that I had needed to run composer to get the dependencies in there - thanks - network tab sorted it